# Codeigniter libraries and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter, and I'm trying to make a simple login.
I'm trying to send an ajax request into one of my libraries files (User.php).
Inside the user.php I've got the 'Login' method.

```
        public function login($data){
            $this->CI->load->model('School_model');
            $logged = $this->CI->School_model->login($data['name'], $data['pass']);
            if (!empty($logged)){
                $role = $this->CI->School_model->role($logged->role);
                $sesData = [
                    'success'=>'success',
                    'username'=>$logged->name,
                    'role'=>$role,
                    'logged'=>TRUE
                ];
                $this->CI->session->set_userdata($sesData);
            }
            else{
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Bad Reuqest');
                header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                die("Incorrect name or password");
            }
        }
```

Here's my Ajax call, but i don't know how do i reach to this file, so i'm missing the URL. (my base URL is http://localhost/school/)

```
    $('.sub').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            //what should i put here?
            url: 'http://localhost/school/libraries/user',
            type: 'POST',
            //sending login information
            data: getInputs()
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log('Logged in!');
        })
        .fail(function(reqObj, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            $('.error').html(reqObj.responseText);
        });
    });
```

Comment: First of you need to set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';` not good idea `url: 'http://[::1]/school/???????'` use like `url: "<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>"`

Comment: Strange url indeed. Better use absolute url, like /school/libraries/user

Comment: I'm sorry for that weird url, just wanted to demonstrate that i don't know what to put in there, anyway, i can't just reach to /school/libraries/user, i can't access it that way.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 how can i do that if i'm using JS file?

Comment: You can't access libraries from outside, you have to write a controller from where you call the library.

Comment: You can declare a global js variable like ```var BASE_URL = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'``` in your header view and you can use it in your js files as follows :

```url: BASE_URL+ 'school/libraries/user',```

Comment: Your ajax and form URL have to be the same url. They both have to point to the same controller